# Using actual value of cell instead of shown text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell that does two calculations and shows the answer as "30+200" but I want another cell to use that cell's value/total of 230 in a calculation.

Comment: You could use `=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"+")*1)` or sum the cells that your _30+200_ formula gets its reference from.

Comment: Or, you can define a name in name manager as `EVAL()` which refers to `=LAMBDA(α,EVALUATE(α))` and enter in cell `B1` as `=EVAL(A1)` which will return as `230`

Comment: I don't have TEXTSPLIT in my version of excel and I don't understand the EVAL method

Comment: Figured it out!!! I used =SUM(LEFT(AN11,FIND("+",AN11)-2),RIGHT(AN11,FIND("+",AN11)))

Comment: That seems you are not in `MS365` then you could try this formula: `=SUM(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"))`

Comment: Try this variant:
`=LEFT(AN11,FIND("+",AN11)-1)+MID(AN11,FIND("+",AN11),10)`
Should be more reliable than yours.